# How to send message with a single tap

Tags: ios, objective-c, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

I want to send message to multiple people with single  tap i..e, without opening the `MFMessageViewController` .

I'll Configure the senders list and message to be send with `NSUserDefaults`.

Can we able to send without viewing the `MFMessageViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible with the Public SDK.

The user will always have to send the messages them selfs. This is probably done to make sure that you do not send 100 of messages to paid services.